# GAN Output Gradient Calculation

Tags: loss-function, backpropagation, gan

Loss function for discriminator, which needs to be maximized: -log(D(x)) + log(1-D(G(z))).
Loss function for generator, which needs to be maximized: log(D(G(z)))

What would the calculation of the loss gradient of the output value of the discriminator look like?
What would the calculation of the loss gradient of the generator output look like?

Comment: Those gradients depend on the specific functions implemented by Generator and Discriminator.

Answer (score 0):

The **loss gradient of the output value of the discriminator** could be calculated as follows:

- For **real data**, the gradient would be -1/D(x) since we want to maximize the log likelihood of D(x) and hence we move in the direction that minimizes D(x).
- For **generated data**, the gradient could be 1/(1 - D(G(z))) since we want to maximize the log likelihood of 1 - D(G(z)) and hence we move in the direction that maximizes 1 - D(G(z)).

The **loss gradient of the generator** output could be calculated as follows:

- The gradient could be 1/D(G(z)) since we want to maximize the log likelihood of D(G(z)) and hence we move in the direction that maximizes D(G(z)).